# GeoServer 2.18 Invalid URL: triangle

Tags: geoserver

We are running GeoServer 2.18 using Tomcat.  In the catalina.out log we are continuously getting  the error message below.  We are almost exclusively using CSS in our layers.  Is anyone familiar with the error below and could explain how to address the issue?

```
@mode "Flat";
[WATERS_TYPE = 'RAPANOS']{
  /* @title Marine - RAPANOS */
  [COWARDINCATEGORY = 'Marine']{
    mark: symbol(triangle);
    mark-size: 9px;
    mark-label-obstacle: true;
    :mark {
      fill: #0000FF;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 0.7;
      stroke-opacity: 0.5;
      fill-opacity: 1.0;
    };
  };




09 Mar 18:37:36 DEBUG [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.

09 Mar 18:37:36 DEBUG [renderer.style] - Exception while scanning for the appropriate mark factory

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: triangle

        at org.geotools.renderer.style.svg.RenderableSVGCache.getRenderableSVG(RenderableSVGCache.java:81)

        at org.geotools.renderer.style.svg.SVGMarkFactory.getShape(SVGMarkFactory.java:48)

        at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.getShape(SLDStyleFactory.java:1377)

        at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createMarkStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:639)

        at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createPointStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:604)

        at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createPointStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:479)

        at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyleInternal(SLDStyleFactory.java:328)

        at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:289)

        at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:262)

        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processSymbolizers(StreamingRenderer.java:2911)

        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processFeature(StreamingRenderer.java:2786)

        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRenderer.java:2618)

        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2189)

        at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:890)

        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:594)

        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:276)

        at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:133)

        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:707)

        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:287)

        at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:110)

        at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:253)

        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor353.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)

        at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:38)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:55)

        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:31)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:73)

        at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:53)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

        at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:50)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)

        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.getMap(Unknown Source)

        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor311.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:879)

        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:265)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)

        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:259)

        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:163)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)

        at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)

        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)

        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)

        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)

        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)

        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)

        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)

        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)

        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)

        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)

        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)

        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)

        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)

        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)

        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)

        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)

        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)

        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)

        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)

        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

09 Mar 18:37:36 DEBUG [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name triangle

09 Mar 18:37:36 DEBUG [renderer.style] - returning triangle

09 Mar 18:37:36 DEBUG [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.

09 Mar 18:37:36 DEBUG [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.

09 Mar 18:37:36 DEBUG [renderer.style] - Exception while scanning for the appropriate mark factory
```

Comment: Do any of your styles have a reference to triangle in them?

Comment: A number of the CSS styles have triangles in them.  We actually have similar errors for squares as well.

Comment: could you add a copy of the style

Comment: Ian,  I pasted the CSS in the question above.  Everything works OK as far as I can tell, but I have been working to figure out errors and anomalies that pop up in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a normal DEBUG statement, to not see them turn your logging level down to PRODUCTION or QUIET.

Comment: Ian, That worked and removed future entries from the log regarding this question.  In your opinion, would it be safe for our organization to run in PRODUCTION mode and only address items that appear to be errors that show up in this mode?

Comment: You only ever need to worry about ERRORs and WARNINGs anything that starts DEBUG is for the developers to use. PRODUCTION is designed for production servers.

Comment: Thanks for your help!